# primary decomposition of non-monomial ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I know that there is a known algorithm for computing primary decomposition of monomial ideals. but what about others?
as an example:

Let $R=k[[x,y,z]]$ and $I=(y,z)\cap (x-y)$. is there a Methodical computation?
Apart from the general case, i also want to see how one computes the primary decomposition of  $I$, above.
thanks.

Comment: [This paper may be helpful.](https://www.msri.org/~de/papers/pdfs/1992-001.pdf)

Comment: many thnx. but seems too hard for me. can you help me about $I=(y,z)\cap (x-y)$?------ i've read 8 chapters of atiyah-macdonald & 2 chapters  of BH.

Comment: I don't understand your question: isn't $I$ an intersection of two prime ideals? Then what primary decomposition you are looking for?

Comment: why (x-y) is prime? --- (I see that (y,z) is prime and that (x-y) and (y,z) are not comparable.)